# How to know the parameter name of query string using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a query string with 2 parameters name/DOB and id, in which first parameter name changes according to the necessity with DOB, i.e; either it could be name or DOB at one time, now I want to do something on the basis of parameter name, how can I achieve this.

For example this is the url `www.example.com/detail.aspx?name=john&id=10` it could be `www.example.com/detail.aspx?DOB=10/01/2009?id=10`

pseudo code is something like this

```
if(first parameter name == "DOB")
{
   // do something
}
```

please let me know if I can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The order in which you add the querystring parameters is generally deemed irrelevant. Why do you specifically need this?

Comment: Note that the date format for your DOB parameter could get you into trouble, front slashes can be a problem, even when they are url encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Request.QueryString.AllKeys[0]` to get the first query string key. See [NameValueCollection.AllKeys on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.allkeys.aspx) for more info.

By the way, it's probably a bad design to count on the query string being in any particular order. Instead, check for query string parameters like this...

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["DOB"])
{
//QS contains DB, now make sure it's a valid value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Querystring has a collection of the keys, you can use the following code

```
if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault() == "DOB")
{
   // do something
}
```

Alternately you can use `Contains` to see if the query string has the desired key, not necessarily first.

```
if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("DOB"))
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Just a note, make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your class, as this relies on an extension method.